# JavaFX nested columns using nested object

Tags: java, javafx, nested-object

I have the following data model

```
public interface Foo {
  public DoubleProperty getA();
  public DoubleProperty getB();
}

public interface Bar {
  public Foo getAttribute1();
  public Foo getAttribute2();
}
```

I want to display a list of Bar using a TableView where the A and B are nested columns of the associated attribute, e.g.

```
| Attribute1 | Attribute2 |
|   A  |  B  |   A  |  B  | 
|------------|------------|
```

I can get this working where I set the individual cell value factories, but there is a lot of repetitive code where the only change is getAttribute1() vs getAttribute2().  This model occurs quite frequently, so eliminating
repetitive code would be very useful.

So I started putting together a class that creates the requisite nested columns, something along the lines of:

```
public class FooColumn<S> {
  private TableColumn<S,Double> aColumn;
  private TableColumn<S,Double> bColumn;

  public FooColumn(TableColumn parent) {
    aColumn = new TableColumn<>("A");
    bColumn = new TableColumn<>("B");

    parent.getColumns().addAll(aColumn,bColumn);
  }
}
```

The challenge is in setting the cell value factories for the nested columns.  I do not want to use reflection to make the binding.  One solution that comes to mind is to make FooColumn abstract and make concrete classes for Attribute1 and Attribute2 that define the appropriate cell value factories.  I find that solution better than the repetitive code approach, but less than ideal.  Another solution is to define a cell value factory in the parent column that returns the appropriate attribute and not display the value.  The nested columns then use the parent column cell value method to get the Foo object.  A third solution is to pass a Callback<S,Foo> as part of the constructor that accesses the appropriate attribute in Bar.

The third solution seems to be the cleanest approach, but I feel like I am missing a more elegant solution and any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. You do, e.g. `column1a.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().getAttribute1.getA());`

Comment: Inside the FooColumn class there is no knowledge which attribute is being accessed.  Thus, I would need to set the cell value factory for each nested column outside of FooColumn.

Comment: Your solution is the original implementation that had a lot of repetitive code.  It works, but it is a copy-pasta fest

Comment: That’s the normal approach. It’s not clear why you’re subclassing `TableColumn`... Just write a method with the appropriate parameters that creates the columns. (Prefer creational patterns to inheritance.)

Comment: I'm not subclassing TableColumn, but you are correct that a creational pattern is a good approach.  It seems your solution is a variant of the third solution.

Comment: Remember you can pass functions as parameters to a method (`createColumn(Bar::getAttribute1)`). I’ll post a solution when I’m back at the computer. (And yes, sorry, I misread the code somehow.)

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a creational method such as this:

```
public record NamedFunction<S,T>(String title, Function<S,T>> property) ;

public TableColumn<Bar, Foo> createParentColumn(String title, Function<Bar, Foo> fooProvider, List<NamedFunction<Foo, DoubleProperty> properties) {
    TableColumn<Bar, Foo> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
    for (NamedFunction func : properties) {
        TableColumn<Bar, Double> childCol = new TableColumn<>(func.title());
        childCol.setCellValueFactory(cd -> properties.property().apply(fooProvider.apply(cd.getValue())));
        col.getColumns().add(childCol);
    }
    return col ;
}
```

And then,  for your example:

```
List<NamedFunction<Foo, DoubleProperty>> barProperties = List.of(
    new NamedFunction("A", Foo::getA),
    new NamedFunction("B", Foo::getB)
);
List<NamedFunction<Bar, Foo>> fooProperties = List.of(
    new NamedFunction(Bar::getAttribute1),
    new NamedFunction(Bar::getAttribute2)
);

TableView<Bar> table = new TableView<>();
for NamedFunction<Bar, Foo> f : fooProperties) {
    table.getColumns().add(createParentColumn(f.title(), f.property(), barProperties);
}
```

Using reflection over explicit execution of methods by name is a trade-off between reduction of code in the first case, versus simplicity and performance in the second.

The benefit of this approach is that you isolate the opportunities to choose between those. In the example above, those are isolated to the creation of the lists.